# How do I fix many visitors leaving my park unhappy or sick?

Tags: idle-theme-park-tycoon

I'm playing [Idle Theme Park Tycoon](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/idle-theme-park-tycoon-game/id1460772578) on my iPad, and I'm running into the issue where my park is too popular. I'm currently on the Space Ride park level. I'm getting A LOT of visitors, and even though nearly all my rides are already at maximum capacity for queue length and allowed riders, I'm still having a lot of loose people running in my park who are unable to queue up for rides because there are already 32 people waiting, and apparently eventually they leave my park frustrated and angry, with a red emoji above their heads. There are also people who leave my park with a nauseous emoji above their heads. I'm worried that this might negatively impact my park. Is there anything I can do about this?